# How to access variables handled by angularjs, using vuejs?

Tags: angularjs, vue.js

I have an `angularjs` project and I'm trying to create a page made in angular, using `Vuejs`.

I've been reading `vuejs`'s documentation but I can't quite figure out how to handle the variables used with angular inside my `.twig` file.

For instance, if I have something like this:

```
<section id="ProjectController">
    <div class="list-default list-lg">
        <a class="animated fade-in-right" v-for="project in projects" ng-href="{% verbatim %}{{ project.url }}{% endverbatim %}">
            <project project-on-delete="onDelete" project-show-delete-action="true" project-allow-delete="project.ownerId == user.id" project-show-progress="true" project-show-status="true"></project>
        </a>
    </div>
</section>
```

I know `ng-controller`= id, `ng-repeat` = v-for

And I have this basic js:

```
    var ProjectController = new Vue({
      ready: function () {
        this.fetchUsers();
      }
      el: '#ProjectController',
      data: {
        projects: null
      },
      methods:{
       getProjects: function(){ 
         this.projects = JSON.parse('array with cluster, id, name, ownerId, etc');
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
    this.getProjects();
  }
})
```

Now, how can I access those variables (Like `project` or `id`) inside the json array?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
var projectCtrl = $("#ProjectController").scope();
```

**EDIT**

if the `project' directive has isolate scope, then you'll have to enter its scope by using

```
var projectDirectiveCtrl = $("#ProjectController project").isolateScope();
```

or

```
var $project = angular.element("[id='ProjectController']").scope();
```

since jqLite doesn't support `#` selector